# Why doesn't my javascript function output right?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I thought my code should change exampleoutput but it says 0 (I am running this on p5.js). I changed `outputVar=1;` on line 6 to `exampleoutput=1;` and it works but I want to be able to change it.

My code:

```js
var exampleoutput = 0;

var makeButton = function (
  x1,
  x2,
  y1,
  y2,
  outputVar,
  haveShape,
  colorR,
  colorG,
  colorB
) {
  mouseClicked = function () {
    if (mouseX >= x1 && mouseX <= x2 && mouseY >= y1 && mouseY <= y2) {
      outputVar = 1;
    }
  };
  if (haveShape === 1) {
    fill(colorR, colorG, colorB);
    rect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
  }
};

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);

  makeButton(50, 100, 50, 100, exampleoutput, 1, 0, 0, 0);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  text(exampleoutput, 200, 200);
}
```

Comment: Well that's not how JavaScript works. You can have your function return the corrected value of `outputVar` and then when you call the function you can assign that return value to `exampleoutput`.

Comment: The full answer here involves reading through the documentation for [how functions in JS work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) but if you just want the summary for what's going on here, search that page for "Parameters are essentially passed to functions by value" and read that section. You're not passing `exampleoutput` into the function, you're passing _the value that `exampleoutput` points to_ into the function. JS does not preserve "where it came from" once you're inside the function.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish exactly at a high level, what feature you're trying to implement? This seems like a [strange way to try to solve whatever problem you're solving](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Do you want a mouse click in a region to trigger a text change? Once you clarify the goal, please update the title to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a click "listener" to a "button" (quotes used because these concepts don't actually exist when you're working with a canvas--consider using an [actual DOM button](https://p5js.org/examples/dom-input-and-button.html)) can be done by adding a single `mouseClicked` global function:

```js
const x1 = 50;
const x2 = 100;
const y1 = 50;
const y2 = 100;
let isButtonClicked = false;

function mouseClicked() {
  if (
    mouseX >= x1 &&
    mouseX <= x2 &&
    mouseY >= y1 &&
    mouseY <= y2
  ) {
    isButtonClicked = true;
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);
  rect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  text(isButtonClicked ? "yes" : "no", 20, 20);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Or by using `mouseIsPressed` in your `draw()` loop:

```js
const x1 = 50;
const x2 = 100;
const y1 = 50;
const y2 = 100;

function buttonClicked() {
  return (
    mouseX >= x1 &&
    mouseX <= x2 &&
    mouseY >= y1 &&
    mouseY <= y2
  );
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);
  rect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  const t = mouseIsPressed && buttonClicked() ? "yes" : "no";
  text(t, 20, 20);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.js"></script>
```

The behavior is different--the top version is a one-off click and adjustments would be necessary to make it release. An easier approach is the bottom version, which uses release and may be the behavior you want.

There are other approaches, but it's hard to offer further suggestions without more context. If you want to use multiple buttons, you'll want to keep coordinates for each button in an array and loop over them to see which one (if any) was pressed.